# 2D Transformation in SWT - converting coordinates with Transform

Tags: java, swt, 2d, transform

Assumed I aplied a 2D Transformation to the gc:

```
  Transform trRotated = new Transform(display);
  trRotated.rotate(-90);
  gc.setTransform(trRotated);
```

The coordinate system is rotated counterclockwise - X achse points up, Y achse points to the right.

Assumed I would like to handle the coordinates, as if Y would point down, and X would point right.

E.g. I would like to input the green point's coordinates which are (2,3) before transformation.
And it should be converted to (-3,2) which are the coordinates, if the transformation is considered.

**Question:**
Do I have to convert coordinates manually or is there som way to do the conversion automagically, maybe by using the available `transform`?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question in right way, but draw whatever you want to GC context, then set transformations a voila result is transformed as you selected by setting `Transformation` instance.. Nothing needs to be converted manually, just use the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the context of rotate function you need.

But, for rotate a rectangle in theta degrees (e.g. Math.toRadians(90)) can use:

```
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(theta, rect.getX() + rect.width/2, rect.getY() + rect.height/2);
g2.transform(transform);
```